# Yii2 Ajax возвращает всю страницу

Tags: php, ajax, controller, action

Есть карточка товара, по клику на заказ которой передаю ajax запрос на экшн контроллера, где хочу производить обработку данных. Но ajax при любом раскладе возвращает всю страницу.

Обработчик кнопки:

```
$script = <<< JS
    $('#createOrder').on("click", function(){
        var size = $('#size').val();
        var color = $('#color').val();
        var id_product = $(this).data('id');
        var count = $('#counter').val();
        $.ajax({
            type     : "GET",
            url: "../web/index.php?r=site/create-order",
            data: {
                id_product: id_product,
                count: count,
                color: color,
                size: size
            },
            success: function (data) { 
                console.log(data);
    }
        })
    });
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Экшн контроллера:

```
public function actionCreateOrder()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            return 'TEST';
        }

    }
```

Но возвращается страница, генерируемая actionIndex:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $products = Products::getDiscounts();
        return $this->render('index', compact('products'));
    }
```

Comment: может стоит указать относительный путь сайта?  /index.php?r=site/create-order

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177008/yii2-isajax-returns-false

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Экш даже не срабатывает, делал проверку на isAjax